# CodeIgniter - Simple base_url question

Tags: css, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, base-url

I'm a bit confused here.

I have a simple controller which loads a view. The view contains a form and links some CSS files. I don't really want to do `../../css/global.css`in my link tag. I want to use the base_url() method and then go /css/.

I know a friend uses the following:

```
  <link href="{base_url}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, I can't get that to work. He uses CodeIgniter 1.7 though, I'm using the latest (2.something) version. I'm new to CodeIgniter and I wanted to mess around with it, but I can't even link a simple CSS file :(

My view is in `/logic/views/index.php`, my css files are in `/css/`

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: the syntax `{base_url}` may be from CI's [template parsing class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html) - or I believe that [smarty templates](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison) use this syntax too. (also you could just use an absolute path - `/css/global.css`) but your app will be more portable using the `base_url`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that base_url is a function in ci 2+ so try this instead

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/style.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It depends how you defined base_url if you did an ending slash otherwise just add a slash so

```
/css/style.css
```

Comment: I tried this, probably should have mentioned it. When I do this `  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/global.css" media="all" />`, my page cuts off right before the link tag. I don't get any errors, it just cuts off :(

Comment: I had to load the URL helper as stated below.. And then I had some problems with my .htaccess file. It worked now, thanks a lot!

Comment: base_url() has existed since version 1.2

Answer (score 4):

I put my css files in the root directory and link them like this

```
<?php echo link_tag('css/forie.css'); ?>  
<?php echo link_tag('css/reset.css'); ?>
<?php echo link_tag('css/main.css'); ?>
```

Using link_tag allows me to access them easily

Answer (score 3):

You can use the URL helper to ease your URL woes :)

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

**Usage**

Load it up in your bootstrap

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

And whenever you need something you can use

```
echo site_url("/css/style.css");
```

Or just assign it as a handy base url so you can use it wherever you want.

```
$base_url = site_url('/');
<link href="{$base_url}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php echo 'base url is' . $base_url?>
```

**Note**

Remember to define your proper base URL in the config file before using this method.

Comment: Thanks. I used the method Tyler Rice provided in combination with part of yours, apparently I forgot to load the URL helper (silly me). Now I just have to fix something else because well.. they get linked correctly in my source code, but they still don't get loaded.

Answer (score 1):

for CI 2+ you can add $this->load->helper('url'); before you load the view and then add 
<link href="<?php echo base_url().'css/style.css';?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> into your view file.

Comment: This does not generate relative path structure, but provides full path including http:// for every css etc.