# echo base_url not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use:

```
href=<?php echo base_url('contactus.php');?>
```

where `contactus.php` is a file under views and I have loaded helper `url` under autoload. Please help me with correct syntax.

Also, I have loaded the file in controller but it is still not working. My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('homeview');
  }

  function contact()
  {
    $this->load->view('contactus');
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: `contact.php` or `contactus.php` ?

Comment: sorry ... I have contacus.php... in base_url as well.. i wrote mistake while typing

Comment: check if you've configured your $config['base_url'] in applicationconfig/config.php

Comment: Yes, I have config the base_url.

Comment: I have a navmenu with:home product contactus
I am trying to put href link for that contactus page using php base_url... sory if I m not clear in aksing questions

Comment: Did my answer below solved your problem?

Comment: This shud work <?php echo base_url().'index.php/home/contact';?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//use following to redirect page using base_url()
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/controller_class/functionName';?>">contact us</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

`base_url` is a function without arguments and you are passing the parameter that's why it is not echoing.

Use this code:

```
href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/home/contact'; ?>"
```

Or better yet:

```
href="<?php echo site_url('home/contact'); ?>"
```

Or even better:

```
<?php echo anchor('home/contact', 'Contact Us'); ?>
```

References:

- [CodeIgniter - Simple base_url question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450095/codeigniter-simple-base-url-question)
- [CodeIgniter's URL helpers](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: It says the page requested not found when i did: base_url().'index.php/home/contactus.php' "home is my controller page"

Comment: 404 page not found! 
The request page not found!! still the same problem!! sorry to bug you all for sth that might be silly questions... :(

Comment: <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/home/contactus'; ?>">Contact US</a></li>
this is my actual line of code
following is the code in controller page home.php
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('homeview');
    }

    function contact() {
        $this->load->view('contactus');
    }

}

?>

Comment: Do you have a controller name with home and a function in it with name contact?

Comment: @SHANKAR your controller method is called `contact` not `contactus`, so it should be `base_url().'index.php/home/contact'`, although I'd advice you to use `site_url` like this: `site_url('home/contact')`

Comment: @SHANKAR as the Sona say that check that do you have controller with name home and action contactus in home controller.

Comment: And please check you have a php page in VIEWS folder which you have mentioned in method

Comment: @Mischa: you way got some better: now its saying unable to load the file but I have loaded like:
function contact() {
        $this->load->view('contactus');
    }

Comment: Are you sure that contactus.php in VIEWS folder?

Comment: Hey guys thankx!! Its working now... thank you all for your prompt help!! I can move furthe... :)

Comment: @Mischa: i m quite new to stackoverflow: It had to be donw within 15 min.. but its already quite late... can't do it... :(

Answer (score 1):

why are you linking view file? View files are supposed to be rendered not linked directly. You should write controller and load view inside that controller. Codeigniter is a MVC framework. Research more on MVC pattern. And you can use site_url($path) function which accepts arguments instead of base_url() if you want to pass paramater to generate urls.